# Convert nvarchar to Int using Case When

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently, i'm trying to convert '20190208-10h9m/1/1' to data type int. This string is identified under column String_Value. In addition, I'm pivoting using Case when syntax.

I've tried:

```
CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'ID_TABLET' TEHN PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE ELSE 0 END), CAST(PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE As nvarchar) As ID_TABLET
```

I get a converting error.

Full syntax below:

```
Select
    PTXMEDE.ME,
    (CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'ID_TABLET' THEN PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE ELSE 0 END),CAST(PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE As nvarchar) As ID_TABLET,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'Q1_MD' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As Q1_MD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'Q1_FPROB' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As Q1_FPROB,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'Q1_RESULT' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As Q1_RESULT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'WEIGHT' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As WEIGHT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'HARDNESS' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As HARDNESS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'WEIGHT.T2+' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As WEIGHTT2ULIMIT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'WEIGHT.T2-' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As WEIGHTT2LLIMIT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'HARDNESS.T2-' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As HARDNESST2LLIMIT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'CQA1Quality' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As CQA1Quality,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'CQA2Quality' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As CQA2Quality,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'CQA3Quality' THEN PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE ELSE 0 END) As CQA2Quality,
    PTXMEDE.DATE_LOCAL,
    PTXMEDE.SEQUENCE
FROM
   PTXMEDE
   JOIN PTXMIIF ON 
   PTXMIIF.ME = PTXMEDE.ME

WHERE
   PTXMEDE.ME IN (
       SELECT ME FROM PTXME
       WHERE CX_STRING_4 = '20190210-6h31m'
       AND MT = 'CDC_CU'
   )
   GROUP By PTXMEDE.ME, PTXMEDE.DATE_LOCAL,PTXMEDE.NUM_VALUE,PTXMEDE.SEQUENCE,PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE, PTXMEDE.PAT_ID
```

My Expected result is to be able to list the value under STRING_VALUE Column

Comment: What about `... ELSE '0' ` [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You say *"i'm trying to convert '20190208-10h9m/1/1' to data type int"*; what integer does that string represent exactly..? It looks closer to a date, but it's clearly not that either.

Comment: @Larnu : Its partially date, then concatenation of batch information that is manually entered data value. the pattern will always the same.

Comment: But that doesn't say what `int` value that should be @Diego83.

Comment: @Larnu: The value is it should be is 20190208-10h9m/1/1 but sql was giving this converting error, to convert to int. Actually, I didn't need to convert it. This error was taking me down a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

All branches of a `CASE` expression must have the same type in SQL.  An "exception" to this would be where they *don't* have the same type, but the database does some implicit converting to right things (e.g. such as in MySQL).  Here is a corrected version of your `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'ID_TABLET' THEN PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE ELSE '0' END
```

This would make the `CASE` expression output all text.  If `PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE` could be converted to an integer, then in theory you could also use this:

```
CASE WHEN PTXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'ID_TABLET' THEN CAST(PTXMEDE.STRING_VALUE AS INT) ELSE 0 END
```

This would have the `CASE` expression return an integer value.

Comment: It's about _Data type precedence_.

Comment: I've just applied this and it worked. Is there a way to cascade the String_value based on common value column?   Within the data, the ID_Tablet is the only populated value for the row. But per sequence, there are other data values captured, but they don't have the ID_Tablet listed for them.

ID_TABLET                       SEQUENCE       Q1_FPROB
20190208-10h9m/1/1                0                          0
      0                                          0                       12.24